# How to express this action in English? "Please, don't face up drinking like that" or "Please, don't drink with the bottle being upside down like that"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Ok, My little daughter always drinks by facing up & holding the water bottle upside down like this picture. This is not good because she may choke on the water.

[image]

I want her to drink like the man in this picture. The bottle should be held horizontally.

[image]

---

> **[face up/down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/face_1#face_idmg_6)** ​   (of a person) with your face and stomach facing upwards/downwards
>
> She lay face down on the bed.

---

> [upside down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upside-down_1?q=upside%20down) (adj) in a position in which the top of something is
>   where the bottom is normally found and the bottom is where the top is
>   normally found
>
> The painting looks like it's upside down to me.

---

> **[upside down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upside-down_2)** adverb: ​in or into a position in which the top of something is where the bottom is normally found and the bottom is
>   where the top is normally found
>
> The canoe floated upside down on the lake.

---

How to express this action in English? "**Please, don't face up drinking like that**" or "**Please, don't drink with the bottle being held upside down like that**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

> Don't tilt your head so far back when you drink from the bottle (keep it level)

(Similar to Kate's comment on the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

For a little kid I’d simply use something like:

> “Sit up straight when you’re drinking your water!”

or

> “Stand up straight when you’re drinking your water!”

etc.

Comment: but, what if the kid is standing, so say "stand up straight when you’re drinking your water!"?

Comment: Or "Don't tip your head back when you're drinking!"

Comment: @Tom: yep, good. I’ve added that to the answer. And overall, the reason I prefer the “...up straight” form over Kate’s “don’t tip” version, despite her phrasing more accurately matching that of the question than mine does, is simply that for a little kid I think mine would be more easily understood. Bottom line is, if faced with the situation as describe—-i.e. a little kid who’s about to waterboard herself with her sippy cup — I can’t envisage myself choosing Kate’s more precise but also more complex version.